# How to set the UISlider.value to AVPlayer current playing Time (SWIFT)

Tags: swift

I have a UISlider and I need to move the current playing time of the AVplayer to the value in the UISlider. I know the equivalent in AVAudioPlayer but I cant seem to replicate it using AVPlayer

```
@IBAction func audioSliderChanged(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (audioPlayer.rate > 0 && audioPlayer.error == nil) {
        //This is the equivalent if using AVAudioPlayer
        audioPlayer.currentTime = NSTimeInterval(audioSlider.value)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the AVPlayer's `seekToTime()` method — but you have to express the target time as a CMTime, not as an NSTimeInterval.